# Routing issue? Rails First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

UPDATE:  I am an idiot.  I added the @answers to the users controller instead of the questions controller.  now that I changed it to questions controller it is showing. I am having submission errors, but I will start a new thread if I can't figure them out.

I have read a couple dozen of the related questions and tried the solutions without success. I'm wondering if I have my routing set up incorrectly.  This is the error I am getting:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty on line 5
```

Here is my form code.  It is an answer form, but it is being shown on the questions index page under a specific question.

```
<%= form_for @answer do |answer| %>               <<< LINE GENERATING ERROR
  <%= answer.label :answer, "What do you think?" %>
  <%= answer.text_area :answer %>
  <%= answer.button %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my routing information:

```
resources :answers
get 'answers/new' => 'questions#index'
post 'answers' => 'questions#index'
```

Here is my answers_controller information:

class AnswersController < ApplicationController

```
def index
  @answers = Answer.all
end

def new
  @answer = Answer.new
end

def create
  @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)

  if @answer.save
    redirect_to root
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def answer_params
  params.require(:answer).permit(:answer, :users_id, :questions_id)
end
```

Comment: Sounds like it's telling you @answer is nil - is it?

Comment: You are expecting your form params to come in answers controller so why do you have `get 'answers/new' => 'questions#index'` and `post 'answers' => 'questions#index'` routes?

Comment: @FrederickCheung - there are currently no answers in the DB, this form is so I can add some.  So I guess yes, it's nil?

Comment: @Mandeep because this the default routes for getting and posting new answers is /answers and /answers/new but I want to show this form and have those actions occur on the questions#index page.

Comment: where `form_for` is located? and which route cause this error?

Comment: I think you should post your question controller on.

Comment: @IS04 the form_for is located on the index.html.erb in my questions view folder

Comment: In `questions#index` there should assign `@answer` to a new answer, or you will get the nil error instead .

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to form_for can't be nil - rails can't tell that that you want to create an answer (the instance variable may be called @answer but form for doesn't know the name of the variable passed to it, only the value)

In cases like this, the easiest is something like

```
<%= form_for Answer.new do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Alternatively you could leave your view unchanged and set @answer in the controller that is rendering this view (by the sounds of things this is your QuestionsController